Custom Content Block / triggerAuth2 workflow
Setting up my first Custom Content Block, trying to use triggerAuth2 (OAUTH Authentication).

My app should: on load, authenticate with triggerAuth2 (done)
From the result of that, my app should read the authCode (done)
via the backend, get a token and extract the MID from it (done)
I can see in the frontend console the extracted MID, so literally what fails is the very last line of code.
My app should update the frontend DOM with the result from console (fails).

In this screenshot, I have the expected result in the frontend console:

But the app does not update the left hand side frontend HTML - with no error.
What I have so far: I have run the entire authentication loop and have the MID from the token. So I think I am 90% there.
What I am missing is a way to update the DOM / print the MID to the html after I have redirected to the frontend.
For some reason, after the frontend has redirected to itself after auth, I can no longer update the DOM.
Unfortunately, I have not found a single example online of the triggerAuth2 workflow in action, most documentation is "older" than that.
====
Details
My app is barebones.
It consists of

index.html (frontend)

index.js (backend)

An installed package with two components:

Custom Content Block
Marketing Cloud App / Web App



If my page loads without an authcode (just the App's raw url), the frontend will notice it is not authenticated and print something like "Unauthorized".
Then it will run triggerAuth2 function which creates the 1x1 px iframe etc.
triggerAuth2 works. It redirects onto my Apps URL, but this time will append ?code parameter. Once the app frontend loads the second time I extract the authCode from this parameter. See this step:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/authorization-code.html
I send that authCode against the backend (/submit-authCode) which gets a regular SFMC token using the function authAPICall(authCode) - which works as well.
The backend sends updated HTML back to frontend - works, I can see the result it in frontend console. Now the frontend should update the DOM. This does not work.
See code comments where I can observe what works:
index.js (backend)
app.post('/submit-authCode', (req, res) => {
  const { authCode } = req.body;
  // Use the authCode to make a server-to-server call
  authAPICall(authCode)
    .then(accountId => {
        console.log('accountId for sending:', accountId);
 //works
        // send the updated HTML with the MID to frontend
        const updatedHtml = htmlContainerContent.replace('<span id="accountIdSpan"></span>', `<span id="accountIdSpan">${accountId}</span>`);
//works

        res.send(updatedHtml); // Send the updated HTML response
// works -I can see it in frontend console.

        console.log("new html sent")
// executes. I can see this line in backend console.

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    });
});

==
index.html / frontend:
    <script>
    function getAuthCodeFromUrl() {
        var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        var authCode = urlParams.get('code');
        return authCode;
    }


    if (window.location.href === thisAppURL) {
       // Check if the current URL matches the redirect URL -> if no, stop. prevent continuous loop
       // If it matches, proceed with the authentication process:
       sdk.triggerAuth2({
           // this uses a separate web app Installed Package, not the Custom Content Block Package itself
           authURL: authEndpoint,
           clientId: webAppClientId,
           redirectURL: thisAppURL
       });
       // triggerAuth2 returns an authorization code (parameter "code" appended to the redirectUrl;)
       // see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/authorization-code.html

       var accountIdSpan = document.getElementById('accountIdSpan');
       accountIdSpan.innerText = "unauthorized";

    } else {
        // page is accessed with an attached parameter (assume ?code)
        // trade code for token - send to backend for server to server call without CORS issue
        // Get the auth code from the URL
        var authCode = getAuthCodeFromUrl();
        console.log("authCode", authCode);
        authed = true;        
        if (authCode) {
            try {
                fetch('/submit-authCode', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ authCode: authCode })
                })
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        return response.text();
                    } else {
                        throw new Error('Error: ' + response.status + ' - ' + response.statusText);
                    }
                })
                .then(htmlContainerContent => {
                    // Update the content div with the received HTML body
//this works:
                    const containerDiv = document.getElementById('container');
                    console.log("containerDiv",containerDiv)

//this fails with no error:
                    containerDiv.innerHTML = htmlContainerContent;

//this works:
                    console.log("htmlContainerContent",htmlContainerContent)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                throw error; 
            }
        }
    }



==
references
I am more or less following the workflow here:
Custom Content Block
the auth loop (authCode -> token) is documented here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/integration-app-auth-code.html

I will update this with an answer soon. Exactly what you said was the solution, found it today with the help of a colleague.

Hi Jonas, what is your redirect url? keep in mind that what mc does when you call triggerAuth2 is creating an Iframe with your parameters (clientid, uri, secret) you can check it in the DOM, which is a GET request to the redirect URI with the parameter "code", you use this code and retrieve the token then the response from this call is painted in an Iframe within your HTML , this iframe has class="authframe" and its hidden
